# Unable to access the Nagios web interface in Localhost

Tags: nagios

i installed Nagios core in my local system I have followed the [Link](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/install-nagios-4-1-1-ubuntu-16-04.html) to install it but I am unable to access the web interface i am getting the following error

```
<?php
// Allow specifying main window URL for permalinks, etc.
$url = 'main.php';

if ("no" == "yes" && isset($_GET['corewindow'])) {

    // The default window url may have been overridden with a permalink...
    // Parse the URL and remove permalink option from base.
    $a = parse_url($_GET['corewindow']);

    // Build the base url.
    $url = htmlentities($a['path']).'?';
    $url = (isset($a['host'])) ? $a['scheme'].'://'.$a['host'].$url : '/'.$url;

    $query = isset($a['query']) ? $a['query'] : '';
    $pairs = explode('&', $query);
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        $v = explode('=', $pair);
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $key = urlencode($v[0]);
            $val = urlencode(isset($v[1]) ? $v[1] : '');
            $url .= "&$key=$val";
        }
    }
    if (preg_match("/^http:\/\/|^https:\/\/|^\//", $url) != 1)
        $url = "main.php";
}

$this_year = '2018';
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <title>Nagios: <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico">

    <script LANGUAGE="javascript">
        var n = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000000000);
        document.cookie = "NagFormId=" + n.toString(16);
    </script>
</head>

<frameset cols="180,*" style="border: 0px; framespacing: 0px">
    <frame src="side.php" name="side" frameborder="0" style="">
    <frame src="<?php echo $url; ?>" name="main" frameborder="0" style="">

    <noframes>
        <!-- This page requires a web browser which supports frames. -->
        <h2>Nagios Core</h2>
        <p align="center">
            <a href="https://www.nagios.org/">www.nagios.org</a><br>
            Copyright &copy; 2010-<?php echo $this_year; ?> Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors.
            Copyright &copy; 1999-2010 Ethan Galstad<br>
        </p>
        <p>
            <i>Note: These pages require a browser which supports frames</i>
        </p>
    </noframes>
</frameset>

</html>
```

I already worked on Nagios Core recently, I tried to install Nagios Xi in my local system which I couldn't for some issue, since then I am not able to access Nagios core web interface also
Can someone help me how to resolve that issue?
Thank you

Comment: Where is the error message exactly?

Comment: I am getting the above message on the web interface that is when I do https://ipaddress/nagios then instead of Nagios Core UI I am getting the above error

Comment: Are you sure, that you have PHP installed on your server?

Comment: No ! initially, when I am using Nagios also I haven't installed PHP on my server

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `Php` on your system

use this to install php and then restart the nagios service and check

--`sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql`